Parsing text and JSON from a log file with three lines (request, response, record)
I have a .csv log file containing three json lines for each client. For example:
{"name":"John","phone":"08847","politic":"on","ville":"LA","isTest":"false","source":"t3_1"}
{"data":{"name":"John","phone":"+8847","city":"LA","source":"t3_1","cameF":"a1"},"token":"bd67a","isTest":false}
{"data":{"responseId":"R_2hs","city":"LA","cameF":"cpl_agency2","source":"t3_1"},"success":true,"ts":1721394844,"message":null}

I don't understand how you can combine three separate lines into one and then read the json.
Starting reading the file:
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/in/post.csv',
                          delimiter=',',
                          header=None,
                          skiprows=range(0, 42), # skip test row
                          names=['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8', 't9']
                 )


display(df)





t1
t2
t3
t4
t5
t6
t7
t8
t9




0
"name":"John"
"phone":"08847"
"politic":"on"
"ville":"LA"
"isTest":"false"
"source":"t3_1"
Nan
Nan
Nan


1
{"data":{"name":"John"
phone:"+08847"
city:"LA"
source:"t3_1"
cameF:"a1"}
token:"bd67a"
isTest:false}
NaN
NaN


2
{"data:{"responseId":"R_2hs"
city:"LA"
cameF:"a1"
source:"t3_1"}
success:true
ts:1721394844
message:null
NaN
NaN



...



...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...




5001
"name":"Michael"
"phone":"09947"
"politic":"on"
"ville":"FE"
"isTest":"false"
"source":"t3_1"
Nan
Nan


5002
{"data":{"name":"Michael"
phone:"+09947"
city:"FE"
source:"t3_1"
cameF:"a1"}
token:"bd90d"
isTest:false}
NaN


5003
{"data:{"responseId":"R_3gn"
city:"FE"
cameF:"a1"
source:"t3_1"}
success:true
ts:1822404844
message:null}
NaN



I want to get a dataframe like this. Combine three lines into one:



name
phone
politic
ville
isTest
source
name
phone
city
source
cameF
token
rId
city
cameF
source
success
ts
message




John
08847
on
LA
false
t3_1
John
+08847
LA
t3_1
a1
bd67a
R_2hs
LA
a1
t3_1
true
1721394844
null




What exactly do you mean by " .csv log file containing three json lines" ? A CSV (comma-separated values) file where one of the character column includes JSON strings? Or a newline-delimited JSON file that only includes JSON objects, one per line, like in your first code block? Are there just 3 such objects per file? Those objects should be joined by source values (here: t3_1)?

That's file does not contain data in a CSV format.

@md2perpe I was sent a file in this format. Logs are written in csv. This is incorrect, but I can't change it

Your file contains a JSON object per line, not comma-separated values.
You can use pandas.read_json with lines=True to read it.
pandas.read_json doesn't have an option to skip rows, but you can do that by opening the file and calling next. (f is a generator, so calling next will return the next item; so when you use the file to build the dataframe, the rows you called with next will not be in the generator anymore.)
skiprows = 42
with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/in/post.csv", "r") as f:
    for _ in range(skiprows):
        next(f)
    df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True, dtype={"phone": str})

Once you do that, you will have a dataframe that looks like this:
   name  phone politic ville isTest source                                               data  token  success            ts  message
0  John  08847      on    LA  false   t3_1                                                NaN    NaN      NaN           NaN      NaN
1   NaN    nan     NaN   NaN  False    NaN  {'name': 'John', 'phone': '+8847', 'city': 'LA...  bd67a      NaN           NaN      NaN
2   NaN    nan     NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN  {'responseId': 'R_2hs', 'city': 'LA', 'cameF':...    NaN      1.0  1.721395e+09      NaN


From your question we can assume that each line with a 'name' property will be followed by one or more lines with 'data' property, and all of these lines should be condensed into a single row in the dataframe.
To do that, you can first create groups where 'data' is null with df["data"].isna().cumsum() and aggregate with first, excluding column 'data'.
df_g = (
    df.drop(columns="data").groupby(df["data"].isna().cumsum(), as_index=False).first()
)

   name  phone politic ville isTest source  token  success            ts  message
0  John  08847      on    LA  false   t3_1  bd67a      1.0  1.721395e+09      NaN


To get the values from column 'data', use pandas.json_normalize, then create groups starting on rows that are all null (that's a row where 'name' has a value) with data.isna().all(axis=1).cumsum(), and aggregate with first. Reset the index so it will match the index in df_g.
data = pd.json_normalize(df["data"])
data_g = data.groupby(data.isna().all(axis=1).cumsum()).first().reset_index(drop=True)

   name  phone city source cameF responseId
0  John  +8847   LA   t3_1    a1      R_2hs

Note that this will keep only the first non-null value for each column inside 'data'. So column 'cameF' will have a row with value 'a1' and value 'cpl_agency2' will be excluded, which is line with your expected outcome.

Finally, join the grouped dataframes:
out = df_g.join(data_g, how="left", rsuffix="_data")

   name  phone politic ville isTest source  token  success            ts  message name_data phone_data city source_data cameF responseId
0  John  08847      on    LA  false   t3_1  bd67a      1.0  1.721395e+09      NaN      John      +8847   LA        t3_1    a1      R_2hs


Full code:
skiprows = 42
with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/in/post.csv", "r") as f:
    for _ in range(skiprows):
        next(f)
    df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True, dtype={"phone": str})
df_g = (
    df.drop(columns="data").groupby(df["data"].isna().cumsum(), as_index=False).first()
)
data = pd.json_normalize(df["data"])
data_g = data.groupby(data.isna().all(axis=1).cumsum()).first().reset_index(drop=True)
out = df_g.join(data_g, how="left", rsuffix="_data")


thank you, an elegant and versatile solution even if the number of columns changes! Please tell me how to skip rows that don't have json objects?

@mikhailtugushev I've edited my answer to address that.

when I gain enough reputation I will vote for your answer ;) Appriciate your help very much.

import json

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/in/post.csv') as f:
    data = dict()
    data.update(json.loads(next(f)))
    data.update(json.loads(next(f)))
    data.update(json.loads(next(f)))
    print(data)



I wasn't sure about this, but assuming your csv file has one column that is effectively the three lines you showed at the beginning of your post repeating (with a new client every three rows), this code should work:
import json

import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[
        "name",
        "phone",
        "politic",
        "ville",
        "isTest",
        "source",
        "name",
        "phone",
        "city",
        "source",
        "cameF",
        "token",
        "isTest",
        "rId",
        "city",
        "cameF",
        "source",
        "success",
        "ts",
        "message",
    ]
)

with open("test.csv") as f:
    l = []
    count = 0
    for row in f:
        try:
            d = json.loads(row)
        except:
            continue
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k == "data":
                for _, data_v in v.items():
                    l.append(data_v)
            else:
                l.append(v)
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            df = df._append(pd.Series(l, index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
            l, count = [], 0

display(df)

   name  phone politic ville isTest source  name  phone city source cameF  token isTest    rId city        cameF source success          ts message
0  John  08847      on    LA  false   t3_1  John  +8847   LA   t3_1    a1  bd67a  False  R_2hs   LA  cpl_agency2   t3_1    True  1721394844    None


please tell me how to skip lines that don't have json objects. What to do if there are more json parameters in a line?

The code has been updated to skip lines if they aren't valid JSON objects. If the keys/values present in each triplet of JSON objects changes, then it would be best for you to have a set of columns/information that you want to collect information for, and you can then query each JSON object for just the information you want and ignore extra irrelevant information.
